# Difference between $form_id and $form['#id']?

Tags: forms

What's the difference between `$form_id` and `$form['#id']` in `hook_form_alter()` ? Why they have not the same values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Next should make sense:

```
<form action="somepath" id="search-theme-form"> <!-- id = $form['#id'] -->
  <input type="hidden" name="form_id" id="edit-search-theme-form" value="search_theme_form"/> <!-- value = $form_id -->
</form>
```

**Terms:**

`#form['#id']` = [store html form attribute id](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#id):

> Used to populate form elements' id property. In rare cases,
>   you can set this value yourself on a form element, to override the
>   default setting.

`$form_id` - [point to Drupal form function name, in html it's form hidden element](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7):

> The unique string identifying the desired form. If a function with
>   that name exists, it is called to build the form array.